# How to apply selector on one imageview while pressing background layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-selector

I have a layout which contains icon image and a textview.
What i want is to change the background of the icon image while pressing the parent layout.
I have try selector functionality but it only working with the view which is being pressed.If i apply selected on pressing the icon image than it works well but what i want is to change the icon image while user is pressing whole of its parent layout.
This is my layout xml file

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/home_edit_profile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                 >



                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/first_row_image_container"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_edit_profile"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:duplicateParentState="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/home_page_edit_profile_press" 
                        />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/first_row_image_container" 
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/first_row_arrow_container"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
                        android:text="Edit Profile"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:duplicateParentState="true"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/home_page_saparatar_line" 
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: mmh, not sure but maybe you need a `TouchDelegate` - enlarges the touch area of an item - you could do this for your image? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TouchDelegate.html

Comment: Selectors are applicable to single views and not to multiple. If there're two views View A and View B (doesnt matter if they have child-container relationship or not). It seems like that you want to change View B when an action is performed on View A. You can only achieve this with a combination of Selector and some java code.        Let me know if that understanding is correct.

Comment: @GauravArora:you understand perfectly what i want,I am still expecting some help concerning coding point view.A sample example will work great.

Comment: can you post your xml.

Answer (score 3):

//you need to add this line `android:duplicateParentState="true"`

in your both icon and textview.

```
android:duplicateParentState - 
When this attribute is set to true, the view gets its drawable state 
(focused, pressed, etc.) from its direct parent rather than from itself.
```